# SharePoint content type based metadata column is not updating in Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, pnp-js-core

I have created a site column that is a metadata type column. From that site column, I have created a content type that content type is assigned to the Document library. Now I have tried to update that metadata column using JSOM, rest API, and PnP Js core. Still not able to update the metadata column. I can update the single-line text column but I am not able to update the metadata column.

Note: Solution is created in SPFx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to update metadata field

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import { taxonomy, ITerm, ITermData } from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";

public async doStuff(): Promise<void> {

    // Using taxonomy to get term set
    const store = await taxonomy.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    const termset = await store.getTermSetById("10e3b8d1-edef-48ce-82f4-d184c5cd49b2");
    
    // get a single term
    const term = await termset.terms.getByName("Term2").get();

    // get all terms in termset
    const terms = await termset.terms.get();

    // Update single valued taxonomy field and log updated item
    console.log(await this.updateMeta(term, 'ListName', 'Meta', 1));
    
    // Update multi valued taxonomy field and log updated item
    console.log(await this.updateMultiMeta(terms, 'ListName', 'MultiMeta', 1));

  }

public cleanGuid(guid: string): string {
    if (guid !== undefined) {
        return guid.replace('/Guid(', '').replace('/', '').replace(')', '');
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public async updateMeta(term: (ITerm & ITermData), list: string, field: string, itemId: number): Promise<any> {
    const data = {};
    data[field] = {
      "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" },
      "Label": term.Name,
      'TermGuid': this.cleanGuid(term.Id),
      'WssId': '-1'
    };

    return await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(list).items.getById(itemId).update(data);

  }

  public async updateMultiMeta(terms: (ITerm & ITermData)[], listName: string, fieldName: string, itemId: number): Promise<any> {
    const data = {};

    const list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName);
    const field = await list.fields.getByTitle(`${fieldName}_0`).get();

    let termsString: string = '';
    terms.forEach(term => {
      termsString += `-1;#${term.Name}|${this.cleanGuid(term.Id)};#`;
    })

    data[field.InternalName] = termsString;

    return await list.items.getById(itemId).update(data);

  }
```

Comment: This way I can update the metadata column that is directly created from the list or library. But I have created this column in the content type. Still not able to update the metadata column.

Comment: Per my research, there seems no such function to update meta column created in the content type.